# JAVA ¿Como averiguar el valor maximo de cada fila del array bidimensional?

Tags: java, array-bidimensional

```
    int [][] my_array = {{4,8,7,2},{5,2,2,7},{3,3,8,9},{9,8,7,2}};
       
    int valorMaxF=my_array[0][0];
     for(int i=0; i<=3; i++) {
         for(int j=0; j<=3; j++){
             if(valorMaxF<my_array[i][j]) {
                 valorMaxF=my_array[i][j];
             }
            
    }
         System.out.println("El valor max de la fila " + i + " es " + valorMaxF);
}
}
```

- 

Me imprime esto:

El valor max de la fila 0 es 8

El valor max de la fila 1 es 8

El valor max de la fila 2 es 9

El valor max de la fila 3 es 9*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que tienes que hacer el valor máximo de cada fila entonces debes tomar como referencia de comparación la **posición [i, 0]**, por lo que tendrías que poner:

```
int valorMaxF = 0;

for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
   valorMaxF = myArray[i, 0];
   // Segundo for
   //Aquí vendría el resto de tu código 
}
```

Como ves se toma como valor de referencia el primer elemento de cada fila de tu matriz y ese es el que se usa para comparar con los otros elementos de esa fila, tu código te fallaba porque tomabas como referencia el primer elemento de la matriz y no el primer elemento de cada fila de la matriz.